# Hide text field in hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, forms

I have a field field_agent_name. I want to hide this field in my custom module using hook_form_alter.

How to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter format is ideal:

```
function MODULENAME_form_CONTENTTYPE_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_agent_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

[More info on hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

Comment: You dont need to return the $form if its referenced.

Comment: +1 for using form_id_alter. Other than above comment, you do not need $form_state to be passed by reference either.

Comment: @AyeshK according to the docs $form_state should be passed by reference :) the form doesn't need to be returned though

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me:

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'contenttypename_node_form') {
    $form['field_agent_name']['#access'] = 0;
  }
}
```